How to create a custom grid view in FullCalendar with 5-minute minimum event duration in Angular app?
I'm working on an Angular app using the FullCalendar npm package to build a calendar similar to Google Calendar. My goal is to create a 30-minute grid view where I can add events with a minimum duration of 5 minutes, but I'm running into some issues when customizing the appearance of the time grid.
Here's the configuration I’ve set up:
    slotDuration: '00:05:00',
    slotLabelInterval: '01:00:00',

With the above configuration, I can create events with a 5-minute minimum duration. However, I'm trying to customize the grid view so that the time slots look similar to this:

To achieve this, I’ve attempted to adjust the slot height by modifying the CSS:
    .fc .fc-timegrid-slot {
      @apply h-0.5 before:h-0.5 before:flex;
    }

    .fc .fc-timegrid-slot-minor {
      @apply border-transparent h-0.5 before:h-0.5 before:flex;
    }

While this works for the minor slots, the first time-grid slot (the larger time block) does not behave as expected.
Other minor slot:

First time grid slot:

App component .ts
import { Component, signal, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { FullCalendarModule } from '@fullcalendar/angular';
import {
  CalendarOptions,
  DateSelectArg,
  EventClickArg,
  EventApi,
} from '@fullcalendar/core';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';
import { INITIAL_EVENTS, createEventId } from './event-utils';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterOutlet, FullCalendarModule],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.scss',
})
export class AppComponent {
  calendarVisible = signal(true);
  calendarOptions = signal<CalendarOptions>({
    plugins: [interactionPlugin, dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin],
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'today prev next title',
      right: '',
    },
    initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
    initialEvents: INITIAL_EVENTS,
    weekends: true,
    editable: true,
    selectable: true,
    selectMirror: true,
    dayMaxEvents: true,
    select: this.handleDateSelect.bind(this),
    eventClick: this.handleEventClick.bind(this),
    eventsSet: this.handleEvents.bind(this),
    allDaySlot: false,
    eventBackgroundColor: '#1e62eccc',
    eventBorderColor: '#1e62eccc',
    // slotMaxTime: '19:00:00', // Do not show time slots beyond 11 PM
    // slotMinTime: '09:00:00',
    height: '100vh',
    slotDuration: '00:15:00',
    slotLabelInterval: '01:00:00',
    scrollTime: '09:00:00',
    eventDurationEditable: true,
    eventShortHeight: 40,
    buttonText: {
      today: 'This Week',
    },
    nowIndicator: true,
    dayHeaderFormat: {
      weekday: 'short',
      day: 'numeric',
      month: 'short',
    },
    titleFormat: {
      year: 'numeric',
      month: 'long',
      day: 'numeric',
    },
    titleRangeSeparator: ' - ',
    dayHeaderContent: (singleDateObject: any) => {
      const fullDate = singleDateObject.date;
      const day = fullDate.getDay();
      const date = fullDate.getDate();
      const dayNames = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];

      // Get today's date
      const today = new Date();
      const isToday = fullDate.toDateString() === today.toDateString(); // Compare the full date (ignore time)

      // Conditionally apply the 'bg-primary' class if today
      const dateClass = isToday
        ? 'bg-primary rounded-full h-8 w-8 flex justify-center items-center mt-2 font-normal'
        : '';
      const dayClass = isToday
        ? 'text-primary text-[10px] uppercase'
        : 'font-normal text-[10px] uppercase';
      return {
        html: `<p class="${dayClass}">${dayNames[day]}</p>
               <p class="${dateClass}">${date}</p>`,
      };
    },

    /* you can update a remote database when these fire:
    eventAdd:
    eventChange:
    eventRemove:
    */
  });
  currentEvents = signal<EventApi[]>([]);

  constructor(private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  handleWeekendsToggle() {
    this.calendarOptions.update((options) => ({
      ...options,
      weekends: !options.weekends,
    }));
  }

  handleDateSelect(selectInfo: DateSelectArg) {
    const title = prompt('Please enter a new title for your event');
    const calendarApi = selectInfo.view.calendar;

    calendarApi.unselect(); // clear date selection

    if (title) {
      calendarApi.addEvent({
        id: createEventId(),
        title,
        start: selectInfo.startStr,
        end: selectInfo.endStr,
        allDay: selectInfo.allDay,
      });
    }
  }

  handleEventClick(clickInfo: EventClickArg) {
    if (
      confirm(
        `Are you sure you want to delete the event '${clickInfo.event.title}'`
      )
    ) {
      clickInfo.event.remove();
    }
  }

  handleEvents(events: EventApi[]) {
    this.currentEvents.set(events);
    this.changeDetector.detectChanges(); // workaround for pressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError
  }
}

and the scss
/* app.component.scss */
:host {
  @apply block bg-base-700 text-base-200 h-screen rounded; /* Dark base background and light text */
}

.fc-theme-standard {
  @apply bg-base-700 text-base-200; /* FullCalendar background and text */
}

.fc-toolbar {
  @apply bg-base-600 text-base-200 p-2; /* Toolbar background and padding */
}

.fc-daygrid-day,
.fc-timegrid-col {
  @apply bg-base-600 border-base-500; /* Grid cell background and border */
}

.fc-daygrid-day:hover,
.fc-timegrid-col:hover {
  @apply bg-base-500; /* Highlight cell on hover */
}

.fc-event {
  @apply bg-primary text-base-200; /* Event background and text */
}

.fc-scroller {
  //   @apply scrollbar-thin scrollbar-thumb-base-500 scrollbar-track-base-700; /* Scrollbar styling */
}

.fc-button {
  @apply bg-base-500 text-base-200 hover:bg-base-400 border border-base-500 rounded;
}

.fc-button-active {
  @apply bg-primary text-base-200;
}

::ng-deep {
  .fc-theme-standard td,
  .fc-theme-standard th {
    @apply border border-base-500;
  }

  .fc-v-event .fc-event-main {
    @apply bg-primary text-base-200 border-transparent;
  }

  .fc-timegrid-event-harness-inset .fc-timegrid-event,
  .fc-timegrid-event.fc-event-mirror,
  .fc-timegrid-more-link {
    @apply text-base-200 border-transparent ring-0 shadow;
  }

  .fc-theme-standard .fc-scrollgrid {
    @apply border-base-500 rounded;
  }

  .fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner {
    @apply py-2;
  }

  .fc .fc-timegrid-col.fc-day-today {
    @apply bg-primary/5 text-base-200;
  }

  button.fc-button.fc-button-primary {
    @apply bg-transparent rounded-full focus-within:right-0 focus:ring-0 focus-within:outline-none focus:outline-none active:bg-transparent focus-visible:outline-none focus-visible:ring-0 focus-visible:border-0 outline-none outline-0 outline-offset-0;
    @apply hover:bg-base-400 first-of-type:px-4 first-of-type:py-1.5 first-of-type:h-max border-0 first-of-type:border pr-2.5 pl-2 last-of-type:pl-2.5 last-of-type:pr-2 py-2 cursor-pointer #{!important};
  }

  button.fc-today-button.fc-button.fc-button-primary {
    @apply bg-transparent rounded-full text-sm ring-0 border-base-200 text-base-200;
  }

  .fc .fc-timegrid-slot {
    @apply h-4 before:h-4 before:flex;
  }

  .fc .fc-timegrid-slot-minor {
    @apply border-transparent h-4 before:h-4 before:flex;
  }

  .fc-timegrid-event-harness {
    @apply border-base-200 rounded border-l-4;
  }

  .fc-v-event .fc-event-main {
    @apply px-3 py-1;
  }

  .fc-timegrid-event-short .fc-event-main-frame {
    @apply px-0 py-0;
  }

  .fc-toolbar-chunk {
    @apply flex gap-2 items-center;
  }
}

Ignore all the ng deep, will handle it later with custom classes

This looks like a bad idea. If you shrink the slots that small, no-one will be able to reliably select a 5-minute block anyway - it'll be too fiddly, especially on a smaller screen. It might not even be obvious to users that they can even do that. Any 5-minute events shown in those slots would also be so small there'd be no room for a description etc. Sounds like a recipe for UX horror to me.

P.S. What version of fullCalendar are you working from? I just used your custom CSS on the current version, and it doesn't even achieve the effect shown in your second and 3rd screenshots, anyway, as far as I can see - demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/YPKVGWG Do you also have some other CSS in play which is contributing?

I agree with you and I've decided to go with 15 minutes time slot.
So I am using the angular version of the library the version is 6.1.16

I've updated my question with the fulll code.

If you've decided to go with 15 minutes slots instead (good idea!) then presumably you don't really need to ask this question anymore??

I would still like to achieve that look of Google Calendar with less padding in between the slots. It's still too big for my liking.
